# Failure delivering result ResultInfo{} to activity for some pictures

Tags: android, image, android-camera

I have created application which allow user to add photo from gallery or directly from camera. For some pictures it's working correctly but for some app is stoped. Why it's working only for some pictures?

```
 @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode==RESULT_OK){
            if(requestCode==SELECT_FROM_GALLERY||requestCode==TAKE_A_PICTURE){

                Uri selectedImage;
                if(requestCode==SELECT_FROM_GALLERY) {
                    selectedImage = data.getData();
                    picUri=selectedImage;
                }else
                selectedImage=picUri;
                InputStream imageStream = null;
                try {
                    imageStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(selectedImage);
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                Bitmap yourSelectedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);
                Intent intent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
                String path  = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), yourSelectedImage, null, null);
                Uri uri = Uri.parse(path);
                intent.setData(uri);
  // intent.putExtra("crop", "true");
    //                intent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
    //                intent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
                    intent.putExtra("outputX", 500);
                    intent.putExtra("outputY", 500);
                    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, picUri);
                    intent.putExtra("noFaceDetection", true);
                    intent.putExtra("return-data", true);
                    startActivityForResult(intent, CROP_THE_PICTURE);
                }else if (requestCode==CROP_THE_PICTURE){
                    Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
                    cv.put(DateContract.DateEntry.UCZNIOWIE_COLUMN_PICTURE_URI,selectedImage.toString());
                    SQLiteDatabase db=(new DateDbHelper(context,serverToPhoto)).getWritableDatabase();
                    cv.put(DateContract.DateEntry.UCZNIOWIE_COLUMN_PICTURE_URI,selectedImage.toString());
                    db.update(DateContract.DateEntry.DB_TABLE_UCZNIOWIE,cv, DateContract.DateEntry.UCZNIOWIE_COLUMN_ID_UCZNIA+"="+pupilIdToPhoto,null);

                }
            }
        }
```

logs:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=3, result=-1, data=Intent { (has extras) }} to activity {pl.mobidziennik.rodzic/pl.mobidziennik.rodzic.LoginActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3205)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3248)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1200(ActivityThread.java:140)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1285)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at pl.mobidziennik.rodzic.LoginActivity.onActivityResult(LoginActivity.java:194)
    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5390)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3201)
    ... 11 more
```

I think it depends on size of picture.

Comment: Android [does not have a `CROP` `Intent`](https://commonsware.com/blog/2013/01/23/no-android-does-not-have-crop-intent.html). There are many [image cropping libraries available for Android](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/45). Please use one. Beyond that, please tell us which line is line 194 of `LoginActivity`, inside your `onActivityResult()` method.

Comment: Yep, as @CommonsWare mentioned, your problem is caused by a NullpointerException in line 194.

Comment: This is 194. line:
cv.put(DateContract.DateEntry.UCZNIOWIE_COLUMN_PICTURE_URI,selectedImage.toString());
so the selectedImage.toString() is wrong. 
But why it work in some cases? 
OK I will try one of cropping library.

Comment: Changing to image cropping library is working. Thank you